# iOS Swift Paypal Integration Crash with NSInvalidArgumentException Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Downloaded Source from link : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

> payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = false

If I set `payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards to true`, the app crashes with the following exception:

> `* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <PayPalPaymentViewController: 0x10184ec00` **Environment**: mock **languageOrLocale**: en-IN
>
> I'm getting crash when i clicking "pay with card" option

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, not in a link to your Github.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `Project-Bridging-Header.h file`

> import "PayPalMobile.h"
>
> import "CardIO.h"

in viewcontroller.h file and also add `CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate` in your class.